# OWASAP ZAP vulnerability diagnosis cannot be performed with services using Firebase

Tags: firebase, owasp, zap

I use OWASP ZAP to diagnose vulnerabilities in my own web service.
However, the web service function does not work properly via the ZAP proxy. When I checked the ZAP log, an error occurred in the communication of the following URL, and the status code of 504 (Gateway Timeout) was returned.

```
https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Listen/channel?database=xxxxxx
```

Firebase uses not only Firestore, but also Firebase Authentication. However, Firebase Authentication seems to be working.
Does anyone know why Firestore communication causes a 504 error?

The environment of the Web service is as follows.

```
Next.js (Vercel)

Using Firebase functions:
Firebase Authentication
Firebase Storage
Firebase Firestore

※ Firestore and storage can only be accessed by accounts authenticated by Firebase Authentication.
```

If anyone is familiar with it, please teach me.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this issue, and after some research found that [ZAP does not support streaming connections yet](https://groups.google.com/g/zaproxy-users/c/Oel-GnySzuc/m/gTPSoCofAgAJ) and that Firestore keeps network requests open after the server sends data (just in case it wants to send more back the client).

[Enabling `experimentalAutoDetectLongPolling`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.Settings#optional-experimentalforcelongpolling), which forces Firestore to close a connection ASAP, allowed ZAP to work properly.

To do this:

```
firebase.initializeApp({
  ...
});
firebase.firestore().settings({experimentalForceLongPolling: true});
```